# docker connect to windowsservercore via PowerShell remoting

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-compose

I want to test PS remoting between two docker containers. I've the following DockerFile:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest

# Set trusted hosts for PS remoting
RUN winrm s winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="*"}
# Set password -> just for testing!
RUN net user Administrator 1234!password5678

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Enable PS remoting
RUN Enable-PSRemoting -force; if ($?) {Start-Service winrm}

# Keep container alive if started via docker-compose
CMD start-sleep -seconds 3600
```

And the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
   testserver:
      image: 172.23.86.48/myPowerShellImage:latest
      ports:
        - 6985:5985 
        - 6986:5986   

   startpowershelltests:
      image: 172.23.86.48/myPowerShellImage:latest
      ports:
       - 7985:5985 
       - 7986:5986   
      depends_on: 
       - testserver
```

I start the containers via `docker-compose up -d` and attach me to one container via `docker container exec -it powershelltoolsdocker_startpowershelltests_1 powershell`.

In the attached container I perform:

```
 PS C:\> $pw = ConvertTo-SecureString "1234!password5678" -AsPlainText -Force
 PS C:\> $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential  -argumentlist "testserver\Administrator", $pw
 PS C:\> $session = new-pssession -computername testserver -credential $cred
```

`$session = new-pssession -computername testserver -credential $cred` gives me the following error:

> new-pssession : [testserver] Connecting to remote server testserver failed
>   with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see
>   the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.SSessionOpenFailed
>   At line:1 char:12
>   + $session = new-pssession -computername testserver -credential $cred
>   +            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:Re
>      moteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed

Therefore I checked if the target is pingable:

```
 PS C:\> ping testserver

 Pinging testserver [172.21.162.141] with 32 bytes of data:
 Reply from 172.21.162.141: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
 Reply from 172.21.162.141: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
 Reply from 172.21.162.141: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=128
 Reply from 172.21.162.141: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

 Ping statistics for 172.21.162.141:
     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
 Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
     Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 1ms
```

Can someone give me a hint what am I missing.

Thx

Comment: Not sure if you resolve this already since this is an older post. But since you didn't define a port in `New-PSSession` and you didn't give the container a different network, you may be connecting to `5985/5986` which would be your Docker host rather than the container at 7985/7986 Does `new-pssession -computername testserver -credential $cred -port 7986` work?

Comment: Does this work for you from the docker host? Checkout this [thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/using-powershell-on-host-to-connect-to-container/25856/6) where they explain how to test this.

Comment: It's quite possible that you run into the infamous 'second hop' problem. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 1):

Test your connectivity between them using

```
Test-WSMan -ComputerName testserver -Port 7986 -credential $cred
```

Other things to check would include running `winrm quickconfig` within your images, checking if the `winrm` service is running within the image, and checking to make sure the correct value is in the trusted host list of your containers.

```
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts
```

In a Windows domain, you don't typically need to worry about this trust, but I imagine your containers are stand-alone machines.